# I'd like to redirect and setFlash messages

Tags: cakephp-2.6

I tried this CakePHP Blog tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html) over and over again.

But my code can't redirect and not working setFlash messages when adding to posts.

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix this?

I'm now thinking MAMP setting is something wrong because adding process is working when refreshing the index page.

- Mac
- MAMP

Here is my code.

```
<?php
//File: /app/Controller/PostsController.php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if(!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('post', $post);
    }

    public function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Post->create();
            if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error when you save post? and u check if post has been saved in db?

Comment: have you used the code which is required to write in the view file for displaying the session message?

Comment: Indeed the MAMP not showing, tried with Linux Apache it is working . Weird stuff.